# Alfresco : rules between folders

Tags: java, tomcat, alfresco-share

i have two folders under alfresco share site , i want to create a rule between them in order to deny access to folder "folder2" unless folder "folder1" has 6 files inside and one of them must be named "toto.html" , did you know a feature , plug in or a module which do that.

PS , i used record management module 2.0.1-147 but it has a bug in alfresco community 4.2.c (after creating disposition schedule , complete event does not work) seems to be a common bug.
Help please
thx

Answer (score 0):

Your rule would need to monitor any changes (add, delete, update) to files within folder1, then run a [custom action](http://ecmarchitect.com/archives/2012/01/23/1519) to check your conditions and set permissions on folder2. See [Using Rules](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/index.jsp?topic=/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/concepts/library-folder-rules.html).

The action would probably need to be in Java so it can run as admin (using `AuthenticationUtil.runAs()`) to set permissions on folder2 regardless of the caller, although it depends on what scenario/workflow you are trying to implement.